# Java Substring match is failing

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am using a text file to read values from and loading this file into a buffered reader. thereafter i am reading the file line by line and checking if any of line contains one of my keywords (i already have them in a list of String).

However, even though the line contains the keyword i am looking for it does not detects it and gives it a Miss. Here is the code

```
    for(int i=0;i<sortedKeywordList.size();i++)
        {
        String tempString=sortedKeywordList.get(i);
        while(US.readLine()!=null)
        {   
            String str=US.readLine();
            //System.out.println(str);
            if(str.contains(tempString)){
                System.out.println("Contains: "+tempString);
            }               
            else{
                System.out.println("Miss");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: calling `readLine()` twice appears to be the problem, you will skip over half of the lines from your file.

Comment: Do you want to check if ANY of your keywords are in the given line? Then you should switch the order of loops  (as well as fix the issue with `readLine()`) so you'll check the line for every keyword before moving on to the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each keyword, you're iterating through your buffer using readLine(). So after your first keyword, you'll have exhausted your buffer reading and the next keyword test won't even execute since `US.readLine()` is giving you null. You're not re-initialising your reader.

So why not iterate through your file once (using your `readLine()` structure), and then for *each line* iterate through your keywords ?

EDIT: As Hunter as pointed out (above) you're also calling readLine() twice per loop. Once in your loop test and once to check each line for a keyword. I would first of all ensure you're reading the file correctly (simply by printing out each line as you read it)

Answer (score 2):

You're calling US.readLine() twice!

Try instead:

```
String tempString;
String str;

for(...)
{
    tempString = sortedKeywordList.get(i);
    while((str = US.readLine()) != null)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `US.readLine()` once in the while loop entrance and again inside. This moves the input to the next line. Also, compare strings with `.equals()` and to check for substrings using `.contains()`

Comment: he doesn't want to compare strings he wants to see if the string has his substring anywhere in it so using `contains()` is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing two major problems.

1. You've got your loops backwards.

   The way you've written it, it looks at keyword1, and then looks through the whole input, checking for keyword1. Now, there's no more input, and it moves to keyword2, but there's no input left for it to check, so it quickly iterates through the rest of your keywords and quits.

   You want to loop through the input, checking for each keyword, not through the keywords, checking each line of input.

   ```
   while(input){

       for each keyword {
       ...
   ```
2. You're calling `.readLine()` twice for each iteration, effectively skipping every other line.

   Try storing the first line outside of the loop, checking for null in your loop condition, and then calling readLine juuust before the end of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

The dataset in question would be helpful.  Without it, a couple thoughts -

1. Verify the case of the sorted keywords matches case from the text file.  If they are mismatched and you need to support case-insensitive matching, convert both strings to the same case (e.g., use toUpperCase()) then use the contains() call.
2. Verify no extra characters (like linefeeds/etc) appended the end of the sorted keyword.